# Making a say command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, command, discord.py, bots

I want to make a simple say command in discord.py (ex.!say something - the bot says "something" and deletes the command message) but every code I found doesn't work for me. I'm new to python and discord.py and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please check 'how to ask a good question'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a troubleshooting place; you present the code you've worked on, along with the error tracebacks, then we help you with what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something much easier like this:

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, message):
    if message != None
       ctx.channel.send(message)
    elif message == None:
       ctx.channel.send('Give me something to say')
```

Comment: It's more Pythonic to compare `None` via `is` rather than `==` or `!=`. This code block is also not fully answering the question since OP asked to deleted the command.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way I've been able to do this, hope it helps!

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"{text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of useful information on what you can make your discord bot do in the [discord.py API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/). This is an example which should do what you want it to:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Set your bot's intents and command prefix as well as your bot token:

```py
intents = discord.Intents().default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Define a command '!say' with a parameter 'msg', which the bot should reply:

```py
@bot.command(name='say')
async def audit(ctx, msg=None):
    if msg is not None:
        await ctx.send(msg)
```

Now you can delete the message which invoked the command (needs permissions!):

```py
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Finally, run the bot:

```py
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: You really shouldn't spoonfeed the code here, it's a platform that's supposed to help others to learn, to gain knowledge. If you simply give someone the code they aren't gonna learn anything.

Comment: But apart from that this is a really good answer!